# Set up SSL using Mamp Pro 3.4 - Error 'Your connection is not private'

Tags: ssl, localhost, ssl-certificate, mamp-pro

I'm trying to set up an SSL domain on my local machine using Mamp Pro 3.4, but I receive the 'Your connection is not private' once I've finished the SSL setup process and restarted my mamp pro server.

Here's what I'm doing:

- Created the servername 'awesome.com' (its local development, domain
  name doesn't matter)
- Set the port number to 443
- Set the document root to a local folder of my choosing
- head to awesome.com's SSL tab and Create a self-signed certificate
- Assign that certificate folder to my project root (to stay organized)
- Save
- Restart the Mamp Pro server

When I head to my newly set up https://awesome.com site, I receive the message 'Your connection is not private'.

I appreciate whatever help you're able to provide. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your cert is valid for '*.nfshost.com' only. It will not work with 'awesome.com'.

Greetings,

Peter